# Finding a monochromatic right angled triangle of any side.

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

If every point in the plane R^2 is colored red or blue.Prove that given a^2+b^2=c^2 a,b,c are real numbers, one can find a monochromatic triangle with the sides a,b,c respectively. 
(Also is the answer true for more than 2 colors. Provide a proof or counter example adequately.)

Comment: I assume the plane is $\mathbb{Z}^2$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$...

Comment: Please provide your attempts.